# Recommended way to find out what Liferay module provides a class

Tags: liferay, osgi, osgi-bundle, liferay-7

In my Liferay module, I want to use Liferay's `SomeConvenientClass`.

What is the recommended way to find out what module provides that class?
So that I can quickly add it to my `build.gradle`.

Ideally it should either:

- return the module's group/name/version,
- or say with certitude that this class does not exist in Liferay or is not exported.

Until now I go by trial-and-error and copy/paste from `build.gradle` files found in the wild, but I am looking for a more reliable method.
I have Liferay installed, and the source code of the exact same Liferay version, if that helps.

I tried mvnrepository but it does not seem to return anything, example: https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=AuditMessageProcessor

Comment: Be careful simply using any convenient class. Even when a class is exported it is not always part of the public (stable) API. If it is then removed or changed you might get into some problems.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch ?

For example: 
[http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|c:"AuditMessageProcessor"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cc:%22AuditMessageProcessor%22)

Comment: Very convenient! So the `c:` stands for `contains class` I guess? Thanks! I guess this does not find EE-only classes, which is understandable, and means EE users will need another method. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hep, consider accepting the answer if that is what you were looking for :)

As for EE / DXP - those bundles are not in MavenCentral. However if you have a local Nexus (or other Maven repository) it may provide similar search capabilities.

Comment: I would not list as the answer as I would still advocate for gogo shell and search for packages instead. just because he can list his environment (group/name/version) and is using the master and DXP in a liferay installation. But I definitely learned something.

Answer (score 1):

This is more an option than a real thing, but this is how I normally do:

- be familiar with package naming conventions used by liferay and
  inside apps: api, service, web...
- be familiar with the bundle       structure used by liferay, as their
  use of resource folders, which       are not so obvious sometimes...

With that in mind, normally on github is enough to navigate: portal->(kernel/impl/services/apps)->app service/api/web...

But this is a natural process that comes when you spend your day inside the code.

Normally, online jar locators help, but quite often I just rely on my IDE.

On my IDE I have all set-up with Spring dependency management, after I extracted the dependencies using Gogo shell with a running bundle. With Gogo you will not find classes, but modules and packs will be listed. (Gogo is probably what you are looking for btw, as it is able to list with version numbers)

Bottom line, if you need a list as a picture of a running environment, use Gogo.

With regards to the master code, just do not trust it! When it comes to modularity and bundles versioning Liferay is pretty messy (read The dependency management problem here: https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/liferay-digital-experience-platform-review-7-0-ga4).

For your step 7, you will need to chose an api version and code against it. The apis are more stable. You can impose a limit for compatibility on you bnd file, which will cause the system to issue warnings. On your environment, you can catch api changes earlier, let's say, you can ask gradle to use a module with an version number but any patch (using the "+" sing), when you build with a fresh cache or if you change gradle resolution strategy to download you dependencies more frequently, if the build breaks, well, you will see it.

Helpful start point: https://dev.liferay.com/pt/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/using-the-felix-gogo-shell

Comment: Thanks! Just a few typos: "I just really on my IDE", "The your step 7".

Comment: I actually tried many commands with Gogo, but I could not find the syntax that takes a class name and returns the group/package/version... would you mind sharing the exact syntax? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul You gave me a good idea for a blog, not about classes, but version control. https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/preparing-your-ide-for-liferay

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do, it is slow and manual, so don't hesitate to suggest other methods.

1. Download Liferay's source code if you don't have it already.
2. Run `find . -name SomeConvenientClass.java`. If nothing is found, you can be sure the class is not part of Liferay.
3. In the path to the class, find the `src` folder level, and go just under that, so for instance if it is `modules/apps/collaboration/document-library/document-library-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/document/library/web/portlet/action/DLViewMVCRenderCommand.java` then go to `modules/apps/collaboration/document-library/document-library-web/`.
4. Hopefully there is a `bnd.bnd` file there, open it.
5. If the package of the class is not in the `Export-Package` section, then either give up (duplicate Liferay's code into your module), or use some [dark tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023387/226958). If you believe the class should be exported, you can explain your case at https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-70480 for future generations to enjoy.
6. - Module name is the value of `Bundle-SymbolicName`.
   - Version is the value of `Bundle-Version`.
   - Group is probably `com.liferay`, although sometimes it is `com.liferay.portal`, not sure how to tell.
7. Build. Sometimes it fails because Maven repositories are missing a version, for instance [com.liferay.document.library.web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay/com.liferay.document.library.web) 1.0.11 is not available despite being used by DXP fix pack 30. Not sure what to do in such cases except choosing a "similar" version and hoping for the best.