# I have got 4 "Unresolved requirement" but in my build.gradle i haven't this type of dependencies

Tags: java, liferay-7

These are the four requirements i am seeing:

```
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.asset.kernel.service; version="[1.6.0,2.0.0)"

Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.asset.kernel.service; version="[1.6.0,2.0.0)"

Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.document.library.kernel.exception; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"

Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.exportimport.kernel.lar; version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)"
```

Number 4 is the problem about the build.gradle that i write.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.service.tracker.collections", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.46.0"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.core", version: "6.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version: "1.3.0"
    compileOnly group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4'

    compileInclude group: 'net.sf.jtidy', name: 'jtidy', version: 'r938'
    compileInclude group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '1.1.0'
    compileInclude group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf-itext5', version: '9.0.1'}
```

Comment: Can you provide your full build.gradle file?

Comment: i write my full build.gradle but i'm not able to format like a good format  in Stackoverlow!!!

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945612/unresolved-requirement-import-package-for-a-module-not-in-my-build-gradle?rq=1)

Comment: i don't understand what i do because i musn't touch my bnd

Comment: PDFBox is at version 2.0.14, your version 1.1.0 is 9 years old. (unrelated to your problem)